# Grandstream GXP2170 XML provisioning for 7-digit dial plan

Tags: sip, provisioning, phone

I have a need to be able to provision a dial plan that can prepend the area code to a dialed 7 digit number on Grandstream GXP2170 (config files are very similar between the GXP21XX models) on firmware "Prog 1.0.9.69", the provisioning MUST be done by config file. Grandstream support stated that it works for them and shrugged me off, even after attempting to confirm they understood my needs, and that if this feature doesn't exist then i just need to confirm its nonexistence. We provision via HTTPS delivered XML files and i have checked my servers access.log and can see the file being pulled successfully, however the phone doesn't process it and apply it (if i remove the "<=1941>[2-9]xxxxxx" from the dial plan it downloads and processes immediately) can anyone else confirm this? I was also able to program a working dial plan via the web GUI, but the need is to be able to provision this feature with the config file. Also, the administrators guide says "Note:
This feature is not supported by config files (both .xml and .txt)." but is pretty unclear about what feature they are speaking of, and it just seems silly and backwards to me that the GUI can do something that the config file cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I went to the grandstream forums and found some help. My issue was not in the grandstream configuration but, in fact, XML-based. the "prepend" function uses "<" and ">" but these are special XML characters and had to be replaced in the plain text file as "<" and ">" which are then parsed by the XML parser and sent through to the dial plan! No need to thank me, Tony asks... Tony answers.